# Why mix dry and fresh yeast?

Tags: baking, yeast

We are currently preparing to bake bagels after a recipe by Cynthia Barcomi. Strangely, in that recipe she uses both dry *and* fresh yeast in equal amounts. When searching the internet all I can find is advice on when to use which, but nothing on when to use both.

Can anyone explain why she does this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When both are used, the fresh yeast is for "added flavor", the dry for leavening power.

Another author who does this is Nancy Silverton.

-

Some bakers believe that fresh yeast (a.k.a. *cake yeast* or *wet yeast*) gives a more yeasty flavor to the final product. I don't think it does.

It's also more perishable, (sometimes) more expensive, more difficult to find (and when you do, it may be near its expiration), more challenging to use, and less reliable (re: reproducible outcome).

When I encounter a recipe that calls for it, I convert to instant yeast using this old, but reliable chart: http://www.theartisan.net/convert_yeast_two.htm

If you [search The Fresh Loaf for *instant yeast*](http://www.thefreshloaf.com/searchresults?cx=partner-pub-5060446827351852:9bvu1n-clx1&cof=FORID:9&ie=ISO-8859-1&cow=fresh%20yeast&sa=Search), you'll find more information (that may or may not be reliable).